# What is the condition of a curve to have a tangent at point P?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> A curve in $R^n$ is a continuous map $\gamma :[a,b] \to R^n$.
>
> The image of $\gamma$ is often called curved,too. When there is need to distinguish between different curves with the same image, different functions $\gamma$ are referred to as parameterizations.

For this part, I don't understand why different functions are referred to as parameterizations? Can anyone give me some examples?

> A curve (for simplicity, in $R^3$) passing through a point P is said to have a tangent at P if there is a parametrization$(\xi(t),\eta(t),\zeta(t))$ such that $(\xi^{'}(t))^2 +(\eta^{'}(t))^2+(\zeta^{'}(t))^2$ $\ne 0$
>
> at value of parameter t corresponding to P. In this event, vector $(\xi^{'}(t),\eta^{'}(t),\zeta^{'}(t))$ is called a tangent vector to $\gamma$ at P.

For this part , I don't know why

> $(\xi^{'}(t))^2 +(\eta^{'}(t))^2+(\zeta^{'}(t))^2$ $\ne 0$   $\qquad$  (1)

is necessary for a curve to have a tangent at P.  In $R^2$, doesn't it is enough for a  curve have a tangent if the curve is differentiable at P? Can anyone give me some examples about this condition?

Comment: Who in the world is writing the condition with the squares? A *regular* parameterization is one with nonzero speed at each $t$, so we want the vector $(\xi'(t),\eta'(t),\zeta'(t))$ to be nonzero for each $t$. Done. The tangent line has the velocity vector as its direction vector. [Why did you put all these complex tags on the question? They're not appropriate.]

Comment: @TedShifrin I edit the condition, does it make sense now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why are different functions referred to as parametrizations?

If you've learned about parametric equations, you know that we can define a curve in the plane using a *pair* of equations $x(t),\ y(t)$. The variable $t$ is not associated with any *spatial* axis (like $x$ or $y$), but instead is, well, a *parameter* that $x$ and $y$ can *vary* over so that they trace out a curve. Hence the term *parametrization*.$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$

The reason the notion of *parametrization* comes up in your case is, I think, because different *curves* (in the sense of functions from $[a,b] \to \R^n$) can have the same *images* (i.e. graphs in $\R^2$ or $\R^3$ or $\R^n$). As an example, consider this curve:
\begin{align}
x(t) &= t \\
y(t) &= t^2
\end{align}
If you graph it, you'll see it generates the curve $y=x^2$. Now consider this curve:
\begin{align}
x(t) &= 2t \\
y(t) &= 4t^2
\end{align}
This is definitely a different "curve" than the first one because the functions are different; and yet if you plot it, you get the same graph out: namely $y = x^2$. So we have two different "curves" that "look" identical.

When this happens, we distinguish between the two sets of functions by saying that $(t, t^2)$ and $(2t, 4t^2)$ are different "parametrizations" of the same "curve". The thing you have to remember, though, is sometimes the word "curve" is used interchangeably with a particular parametrization of a curve! That can make things confusing, but usually good authors should only interchange the two if there's no chance of a conflict happening between the two senses of the word "curve".

> Why the requirement that $\xi^{'}(t)^2 + \eta^{'}(t)^2 + \zeta^{'}(t)^2 \neq 0$?

Basically this is saying that a curve is said to have a tangent at a point $P$ if and only if there exists *any* parametrization of the curve that has a non-zero derivative at $P$.

To see why this condition is necessary, consider the curve $y = |x|$. You may remember that it looks like a V with the vertex located at the origin. Obviously, this curve has no tangent at the origin, *but* I could define a parametrization that makes it *look* like it does. For example, this one:
\begin{align}
x(t) &= t^3 \\
y(t) &= |t^3|
\end{align}
If you graph it, you'll see that this is a valid parametrization of $y = |x|$, but if you take the derivative of both at $t = 0$ you'll get that
\begin{align}
x'(0) &= 0 \\
y'(0) &= 0
\end{align}
(If you don't believe me, try graphing $x$ vs $t$ and $y$ vs $t$ on their own separate axes. You'll see they both go flat at $t=0$.)

The non-zero requirement prevents us from incorrectly concluding this curve has a tangent at the origin.

As a bit of an aside, you can also use these kinds of "bad" parametrizations to make it look like a curve that *does* in fact have a tangent *doesn't*. Consider this parametrization of $y=x^2$:
\begin{align}
x(t) &= t^3 \\
y(t) &= t^6
\end{align}
Both of these functions have zero derivative at $t = 0$. Does that mean the curve has no tangent at the origin? No. Because the definition states that if there exists ANY parametrization that has a non-zero derivative at a point, then that point has a tangent. Above, we just happened to find a parametrization that *didn't* work, but we can easily find one that *does*:
\begin{align}
x(t) &= t \\
y(t) &= t^2
\end{align}
The thing with $y = |x|$ is that you won't ever be able to find *any* differentiable parametrization that is non-zero at the origin. Either it won't be differentiable there, or it will be, but it'll be zero.

---

**UPDATE:** In response to the following question posted in a comment:

> Is it impossible to say that a function doesn't have a tangent at a point by using this condition? Because it is impossible to go through ALL parametrizations.

If I understand you correctly, I think the answer is Yes: You can't use the non-zero derivative condition with only one parametrization to prove a particular curve has no tangent. You really would need to check *all* possible parametrizations. That sounds like an impossible task, but we can check all possibilities all at once by letting $x(t), y(t)$ represent an *arbitrary* parametrization.

To see how, here's a sketch of the proof of why $y=|x|$ has no tangent at the origin:

Let $x(t), y(t)$ be **any** parametrization of $y=|x|$, and suppose that both functions are differentiable at the point $t_0$ which satisfies $x(t_0) = y(t_0) = 0$ (i.e. maps the parametrization to the origin). We want to show that the derivatives of both *must* be zero (and hence fail to satisfy the definition of having a tangent). To do that we'll consider whether either of them could possibly be non-zero.

If $y'(t_0) \neq 0$, then that means that $y$ is not flat when it is crossing the $t$ axis: it has some slope at a zero. That means $y$ must be negative at some $t$ values near $t_0$. That is not possible since, being a parametrization of $y=|x|$, it must always be positive. This eliminates the possibility that $y'(t_0)$ could be non-zero.

Consider the case $x'(t_0) \neq 0$. Note that since $y(t) = |x(t)|$, we can take the derivative of both sides at the point $t_0$ and conclude:
\begin{align}
y'(t_0) &= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{|x(t_0+h)| - |x(t_0)|}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{|x(t_0+h)|}{h} \quad \text{since $x(t_0)=0$ by definition}
\end{align}
By the same reasoning made before, since $x'(t_0) \neq 0$, $x$ must be positive near $t_0$ on one side, and negative on the other side. For sake of simplicity, I'll assume that $x$ is positive when $t$ is a little bit *larger* than $t_0$. Now, since $y'(t_0)$ exists, that means it must equal the left- and right-hand limits. In particular, it must equal the right-hand limit:
\begin{align}
y'(t_0) &= \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{|x(t_0 + h)|}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{x(t_0+h)}{h} \quad \text{because $x$ is positive to the right of $t_0$} \\
&= x'(t_0) \neq 0
\end{align}
But this is a contradiction because we've already shown that $y(t_0)$ can't be non-zero. Hence $x(t_0)$ can't be non-zero either. $\square$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Quite detailed and understandable! And also, is it impossible to say that a function doesn't have a tangent at a point by using this condition? Because it is impossible to go through ALL parametrizations.

Comment: @Parting: I edited my answer to include an answer to your follow-up question. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Well written and thorough!